# changing the location of currently running torrents

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

My torrents is currently downloading to `C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads`

I want to change it to another location (say `C:\Downloads`)

But of course the torrents (about 5 of them) have not finished downloading. Is there a way to make a shift or will I have to either wait till they are finished downloading or restart the downloads?

(Windows Vista Home Premium sp 2)

PS: I have both Bittorrent and uTorrent and would like to migrate both of it to another location (in case it works for one but not the other)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Stop the torrent
2. Create the new location (eg. C:\Downloads)
3. Copy/move files from original location (eg.
   C:\Users\Joseph\Downloads) to new location
4. Right click torrent in uTorrent > 'Advanced' > 'Set Download
   Location...' > select the new location
5. Right click again > 'Force Re-Check'
6. Once it's done checking, start the torrent again
7. Repeat for all torrents you want to move